# How to convert from iPhone camera coordinates to view coordinates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I am making an application that uses OpenCV to parse output from the iPhone camera and display the result on the screen.  I know the iPhone camera reads in landscape orientation, so there is a need to convert before displaying the results on the screen.  I figured that I would just need to scale, rotate -90 degrees and then translate (tx=width of image), but that is not working.  I found some sample code online, which is below, but that is not working either for any orientation other than landscape left.

What is the proper way to convert from camera view to user view?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{
    //lock the pixel buffer
    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer( sampleBuffer );
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 ); 

    //declare variables
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);

    //a bunch of OpenCV stuff that finds features in an image and
    // returns a cameraRect

    //translate to view coordinates
    float scaleX = 320 / (float)bufferHeight;
    float scaleY = 460 / (float)bufferWidth;
    deviceRect.origin.x  = 320 - ((cameraRect.y + cameraRect.height) * scaleX); 
    deviceRect.origin.y  =       (cameraRect.x * scaleY);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
}

//elsewhere
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

Edit: By not working, I mean that the rectangle displayed on the screen does not correspond to the matched object that is visible in the preview layer.  I'm detecting faces, and depending on the orientation of the phone deviceRect drawn on the screen is off either a little or a lot from the face that is in the preview layer.  In landscape left, deviceRect matches perfectly the visible face.

Comment: You say it's not working - can you provide some details of how it's not working?